# problem with writing to serial port in python to be used by arduino (to turn on light/move servo etc...)

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

i'm having trouble on instructing my Arduino to execute different if statements by writing to the serial port in python.

I've currently got an LED and resistor connected in series via the GND and ~5 digital pins. I want to switch the LED on when, using python, I access the serial port (COM6 in my case) and write to the serial port '1' and switch the LED off when I write to serial port '2'.

Arduino code:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() 
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    if (Serial.read() == '1')
    {
     digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
     delay(100);
    }
    else if (Serial.read() == '2')
    {
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      delay(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Python code in terminal:

```
In[1]: import serial
In[2]: ser1 = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)
In[3] ser1.write('1'.encode())
Out[3]: 1
```

(Also i dont really understand what the ser1.write(...) command is returning, and the number will change if i try other values in the argument...)

When I try and switch the LED on using

```
ser1.write('1'.encode())
```

the LED switches on, happy days.

However when I try and switch it off by writing into the python terminal:

```
ser1.write('2'.encode())
```

the LED won't turn off...? help plz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Serial.read()` removes the byte from the buffer. The second call to `Serial.read()`, to compare to `'2'`, just returns -1, since there is no more data left.

Read it into a variable and compare that.

```
char c = Serial.read();
if (c == '1')
{
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    delay(100);
}
else if (c == '2')
{
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    delay(100);
}
```